# Why writeBufferSize in abstract class Writer be declared as final?

Tags: java

```
public abstract class Writer implements Appendable, Closeable, Flushable {
    /**
     * Temporary buffer used to hold writes of strings and single characters
     */
    private char[] writeBuffer;
    /**
     * Size of writeBuffer, must be >= 1
     */
    private final int writeBufferSize = 1024;
```

I just want to set the writeBufferSize to a bigger number。Why the designer declared it as final?

Comment: why do you need to change it?

Comment: I think set a bigger number will write faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no point in answering "why": for better or for worse, that's how it was implemented.

Note that in Java 8, this is now a `static final` variable, even more strongly indicating that it is intended to be a constant, and not changeable by users of the class.

Use a [`BufferedWriter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html) instead. This has a constructor allowing you to specify the buffer size:

```
Writer writer = ...;
BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(writer, aBiggerNumber);
```

Comment: If i need write 10 string to disk ,all of these string's length bigger than  writeBufferSize.It will new 10 buffer instances.

Comment: "It will new 10 buffer instances." No, it only creates one buffer, and reuses it.

Comment: @cxco is correct. Looking at `Writer.public void write(String str, int off, int len)` (Java 7) , if the string length exceeds the internal buffer size - an "on the fly" buffer is created/

Comment: @DavidSoroko ...but not if you use [`BufferedWriter`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/io/BufferedWriter.java#219), which is what I suggest doing in this answer.

Comment: Thats right, @cxco is correct wrt  `Writer`, you are correct wrt `BufferedWriter`.

Answer (score 1):

Only the original API designer(s) can tell you that.  With total certainty.

But the flip-side is that if it wasn't a constant then there is a risk that it could be set to a harmful value, either by accident or due to a misunderstanding, or (in the case of untrusted code) to deliberately break things.

But as @AndyTurner points out, this is moot ... and you can easily construct a `Writer` subclass that uses a different write buffer size.